# Class referenced in the manifest, `com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, image-cropper

> Class referenced in the manifest, `com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity`, was not found in the project or the libraries

`CropImageActivity` is not working in Android.
I tried to change the manifest.xml files and update the build.gradle dependencies but nothing worked,
Please Update

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is in Setting.gradle(project setting)

put  jcenter()
and  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
in the flowing only :

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() 
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

}